# $f(r)\in\mathbb R$ $\forall$ real $r<-1$

Tags: complex-analysis

> **$f$ is analytic in {$z:|z|>1$} and $f(r)\in\mathbb R$ $\forall$ real $r>1$. How can I show that the same hold $\forall$ real $r<-1$?**

Please don't solve it completely. I'm just looking for a clue. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: Consider the function $g(z) = \overline{f(\,\overline{z}\,)}$.

Comment: @LukasGeyer: Yup you're right.

Comment: @froggie: But $z\mapsto \overline z$ is not differentiable anywhere in $\mathbb C$.

Comment: It's true that $z\mapsto \overline{z}$ is not holomorphic; it is *antiholomorphic*, and thus $z\mapsto f(\,\overline{z}\,)$ is antiholomorphic. But if I take the conjugate again, $z\mapsto \overline{f(\,\overline{z}\,)}$ becomes holomorphic. If you're not comfortable with this argument, it is possible to check that $z\mapsto \overline{f(\,\overline{z}\,)}$ is holomorphic by appealing to the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: @froggie: Thanks.

Comment: @froggie You could post your comment as an answer (hence I will upvote).